# Azure Search Index Indexer Issues

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are seeing some issues with our indexer throwing an error every other time it tries to run the indexer on our data-source. Our indexer runs on a schedule and we have Sql server "Change Tracking" turned ON for db and the table that we use  for indexing. The indexer runs successfully every other time which is strange. I will attach a picture to show you the indexer status page. The odd thing is it shows an error saying:

"Indexing was stopped because the data source has no change detection policy and corresponding quota of 100000 documents has been reached. To index more documents please add a change detection policy".

So like I mentioned we have the "Change detection policy" set (Change Tracking is ON) and indexer running on a schedule. And it works every other time. We are on a "standard" billing tier so we do not have a quota "100000". We believe that this error might also be contributing to our counts in the index data-source and index table not to match. The indexer is NOT deleting the ID that have been removed from our source table.

I have attached an image to show the status page of our indexer. Please help! We have launched our search and are seeing issues pretty late in the game.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more info.

[image: embedded image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to enable change tracking on the SQL side. You also need to set up an Integrated Change Tracking policy on your Azure Search datasource. This is described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#sql-integrated-change-tracking-policy)

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. I will set the Change Tracking policy.
 Can you explain why it the indexing works every other time. It is very consistent.

Comment: This is because Azure Search enforces a limit on the number of rows that can be indexed *incrementally* without a change detection policy. First time indexer runs, the indexing is not incremental, so the limit doesn't apply. Second time it runs, the indexing is incremental now and the limit applies. After an indexer run ends with `transientFailure` status, the limit does not apply on a subsequent run, but probably it should :)